# MongoDB (Pymongo) use $group and $or is same statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Can we use both $group and $or within same statement with aggregation?

```
query = [{'$group': { '$or': [{'_id' : "$birthYear", 'count': { '$sum': 1 }}] }}]
by_date = list(mycol.aggregate(query))
```

This gives me following error,

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field '$or' must be an accumulator object
```

Following is my sample MongoDB:

```
db.employee.insert([
    {"id":"1","name": "Ricardo Carpio","age": 24, "gender": "Male", "birthYear" : "1995" , "hobby" : "Reading books"},
    {"id":"2","name": "Alice Salpicao","age": 27, "gender": "Female", "birthYear" : "1992" , "hobby" : "Eating"},
    {"id":"3","name": "Cardo Agustin","age": 25, "gender": "Male", "birthYear" : "1996" , "hobby" : "Jogging"},
    {"id":"5","name": "Gamora Yuchi","age": 24, "gender": "Female", "birthYear" : "1995" , "hobby" : "Singing"},
    {"id":"6","name": "Thanos Pink","age": 29, "gender": "Male", "birthYear" : "1990" , "hobby" : "Collecting gems"}
])
```

I am trying to group the count with following statement,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$birthYear",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This works well.

But, I need to add a conditional search based on a field, where `hobby is Eating` using `"$or": [hobby: "Eating"]`

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Please edit this question with sample docs & required o/p..

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can use `$or` with `$group`.  How to do that depends on what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do but the answer does not change regardless.

So [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) can receives 2 fields, `_id` which is mandatory and has to be some kind of constant and any field name which is computed with [accumulator operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulators-group).

So `$or` is not an accumaltor operator which means we can only use it as a constant for the `_id` field.

It would look like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$or: [cond1, cond2, ...]},
            field: ... accumulator op ...
        }
    }
])
```

Which will produce the following result:

```
[
    { // matched true with the $or condition
        _id: true,
        field: [ ... ]
    },
    { // matched false with the $or condition
        _id: false,
        field: [ ... ]
    }
]
```

No other top level usage of `$or` is possible.